# Search for a string in a list of strings for a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have

```
list=['samAsl-----$34.95andkjkdsfaskjjlkjroseDkfj----$38.99','samAsl-----$31.95andkjkdsfaskjjlkjroseDkfj----35.99']
```

I want to search the list and get the value $34.95 for 'sam' and $38.99 for 'rose' and put this in a list.  I know how to find 'sam' and 'rose' but not sure how to get the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try finding floation point numbers

```
import re
re.findall(r"(?<![a-zA-Z:])[-+]?\d*\.?\d+", list)
```

Comment: also you can add $ to find more precisely.

Comment: How would you add the $? re.findall(r"(?<![a-zA-Z:])[-+]?\d*\.?\d+$", list)?

Comment: here is what you can use `\$?(?<![a-zA-Z:])[-+]?\d*\.?\d+`. I have used `\$?` because in your sting last floating don't have preceding $ sign its just a float.